# If I want to create a top-down 2D game should I rotate the camera?

Tags: unity, 2d, camera

Do I have to rotate the camera to top-down view if I want to crate a top-down 2D game or just disable gravity?

Comment: These two aren't necessarily related. You might want to create a top-down game with gravity (e.g.: GTA 1 and 2 both had gravity and jumping)

Comment: So I guess the answer is "depends what you want to do"

Comment: @UnholySheep I want to make 2D top-down quest, should I rotate the camera?

Comment: I (personally) would do it that way. I also believe that it was recommended in one of the official Unity tutorials (for a top-down Asteroids-like game)

Comment: It depends if you want to use the 2D physics system, which by default works on the XY plane. I haven't investigated whether it can be configured to work in XZ.

Comment: I did this once in a 2D game to take advantage of Unity's Navmesh system, which (unless they changed it) bakes into flat surfaces found in XZ only. So there are reasons you may want to do it.

Comment: I would personally start with no rotation because it is much easier to code. If you do need rotation, I would recommend to use a minimap to indicate where is north. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do *whatever you want*.

---

That said, it is worth considering *standards*. Picture your game space as a 2D grid. If you retain the default camera angle, you would be working along the *X* and *Y* axis. If you rotate your camera to a down-facing position, you would be working along the *X* and *Z* axis.

*I* would say "leave the camera the way it is"; it is far more conventional to refer to a position on a 2D plane as "X, Y". While you could easily portray coordinates as "X, Y" to the *user*, you still have to work in "X, Z", *yourself*. Any built in methods that apply to two-dimensional coordinates will also *assume* use of "X, Y", including the directional vectors housed in the `Vector2` class.

Why add another layer of complexity to your project? Use the "X, Y" plane, and stick to 2D standards.